# How to Switch slf4j logger implementation1 to implementation2 at runtime

Tags: java, logging

Assume you have a webapplication, in which you are using your own custom slf4j implementation.
but due to some performance reason you want to switch custom slf4j implementation to any slf4j implementation like (log4j/logback etc) for some time.

one way is you can remove the custom slf4j jar from the classpath and add any log4j/logback jar and redeploy the application.

But can we change this at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with slf4j, except maybe with some extreme Java reflection hackery.

To achieve it, you would need multiple slf4j implementation jars on the classpath. But slf4j expects exactly one implementation to be present. If it finds more than one, it outputs a warning message and chooses the first one it finds. Which implementation is chosen is hard to predict, as it depends on a number of factors including the JVM implementation and the order of jars on the classpath.

So, in summary, no, slf4j was not designed to work this way.